# List comprehension inside dictionary comprehension - scope

Tags: python, algorithm, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I am trying to create a complete graph in a Python Dictionary in 1 line.  But when creating the list comprehension for the values I can not figure out how to specify that the key_value can not appear in the list of values (in graph speak, no self loop).

for n nodes

```
G = {k:[v for v in range(n)] for k in range(n) }
```

results in this (example n = 3)

```
{0: [0, 1, 2], 1: [0, 1, 2], 2: [0, 1, 2]}
```

but what I want is this

```
{0: [1, 2], 1: [0, 2], 2: [0, 1]}
```

But trying something similar to this

```
G = {k:[v for v in range(n) for v !=k] for k in range(n) }
```

will throw an error at the k in the list comprehension.  So k must be out of scope for the list comprehension, which makes sense.

Can G be defined in this method?

Comment: `{ k:[v for v in range(n) if v != k] for k in range(n) }` Can ignore v value similar with current k value.

Comment: Thx Tanveer that is a dumb mistake on my part.  You should post as an answer instead of comment so I can select it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To ignore the `key's value` from the `value` list, you just have to put a validation in your [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
G = { k: [v for v in range(n) if v != k] for k in range(n) }
```

So for `n = 3` you graph `G` would return :-

```
{0: [1, 2], 1: [0, 2], 2: [0, 1]}
```